# httppost timeout error

Tags: android, http-post

I have an android application which posts data to php server using `HttpClient` and httppost. Problem is when I run my application from an actual android device I always get the error

> "send data error: org.apache.http.conn.connectTimeoutException:Connect to / timed out.

However using the device browser I am able to access the server url. It's working fine in emulator.

This is my code

```
try
{
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

   Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
   WriteFile("Response:  "+response.getStatusLine().toString(), ":", ":",
           ":","erlog.txt");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
   WriteFile("send data Error:  "+e.toString(), ":", ":", ":","erlog.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
create variables like this:

```
private static final long CONN_MGR_TIMEOUT = 10000;
private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 50000;
private static final int SO_TIMEOUT = 50000;
```

and use this code with http post:

```
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, CONN_MGR_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONN_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, SO_TIMEOUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you must run the server communications on a separate thread. You can either use an AsyncTask class or change strict mode policy.

Strict mode policy can be changed as follows:

```
ThreadPolicy oldThreadPolicy = StrictMode.getThreadPolicy();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(oldThreadPolicy).permitNetwork().permitDiskReads().permitDiskWrites().build());
```

Although the above method is not advisable, you could have it a go and see it working. Add them to entry activity class.

Also, make sure you added permission settings in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```